# can not select ten million rows from a database using python

Tags: python, postgresql, pyodbc

I am currently attempting to load ten million rows of data using python library pyodbc. Consider the following example where the customer table has over ten million rows, please note jeetl :

```
results = jeetl.dw_command_cursor("select * from Customer")
```

The above works fine if i limit it to just one million rows but falls flat on its face with ten, is there a workaround for this?
Here is the error message i have been seeing:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] Communication error while getting a tuple;\nCommunication    error while getting a tuple (26) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible you're running out of memory?

Comment: This seem like a really bad idea.  Try processing your data in smaller chunks.

Comment: agreed, is there a way of retrieving say the first million processing it and then moving on to the next million via SQL?

Comment: What are you doing with the data? Can't you do that inside SQL before extracting to Python? Can't you use psycopg2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your query result is too large, try checking the max_allowed_packet_size.
For example in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Maybe what you need to do is paging the results:
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Comment: thanks for the response, is there a way of retrieving say the first million processing it and then moving on to the next million via SQL?

Comment: Yes. In the link i posted, it shows you how to select the "limit" and "offset". You can do that inside a "while", and then change SQL query accordingly to get "first million", "second million" and so, until you got all the results needed. Algo maybe u need to "order" the results by primary key not to miss any.